# Making Sense of Twitter v1.1 API

Tags: twitter, server-side

I am completely confused. I have attempted to read about the Twitter API v1.1 and it's requirements. What I am confused about is the server side requirments.

If I want to use *any* data via Twitter API I must use server side authentication? or will I still be able to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline/YOUR_USERNAME.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=2"></script>
```

and show the users timeline? I am lost on an answer and browsing Twitters Docs are confusing me more!

Basically I am asking this: If I want to pull a Twitter Timeline of Tweets I must now use server side authentication to do this. If not come March 2013 my twitter feeds will no longer work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you now need to use authentication for all twitter API requests. The following tutorial is quite useful:

[Using The New Twitter API V1.1](http://www.paulund.co.uk/using-the-new-twitter-api-v1-1)

Comment: Does that mean the 4th bullet under Limitations: "Search does not support authentication meaning all queries are made anonymously." (from this twitter doc - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) is incorrect? And that there is no way to do simple retrospective searches without authentication using api 1.1?